# How to edit formula in excel

Tags: excel

[image]How to change cell ( I73) to formula (= D2 )  where D should be constant and 2 be varying according input from cell M57 ? I have trying to write as ="D" & M57 .

Comment: Try `=Indirect("D" & M57)`

Comment: Thank you very very much Doug Glancy-really really feeling happy

Answer (score 1):

[image]Eg: this is formula double click on it

double click on it to edit formula...

Answer (score 1):

The Image Shows you can you can edit formula by two ways by edit formula bar and 
edit on your formula row by double clicking
[This is showing tour solution..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjlu6.png)

Answer (score 1):

You've been given a solution in a comment from [Doug Glancy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/293078/doug-glancy) which uses the volatile INDIRECT function:

```
=INDIRECT("D" & M57)
```

A non-volatile solution using INDEX would be:

```
=INDEX($D:$D, M57)
```

Comment: Yup, that would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CONCATENATE`, to join two or more text strings into one string.
You can use like this:

```
=CONCATENATE("D",M57)
```

[More Info](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CONCATENATE-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d)